# How can I rotate the image in 3D in matlab?

Tags: image-processing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkmJ5.jpg) this is the picture I want to rotate, assume that I know the rotate angle about the X-Y-Z axis, how to upright correct the image in MATLAB, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it to write an answer, but I think you can use `imwarp` to apply any projective or geometric transformation.

Comment: Do you know what is the relationship between the Homography matrix  H , the intrinsic matrix K and the rotation matrix R